# C# owin web api route index page

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin

`http://localhost:2000/api/{Controller}`

I need to create index page.

URI : `http://localhost:2000/api`

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "api",
routeTemplate: "api"
);
```

And the api

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class Api
{
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("API"));
        return result;
    }
}
```

But when I open `http://localhost:2000/api`, it's not working.

No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI `http://localhost:2000/api`.

Comment: Does http://localhost:2000/ work? http://localhost:2000/api/api ?

Comment: @mjwills yes,but localhost:2000/api and localhost:2000/api/api ,  it show No HTTP resource was found

Comment: have you enabled attribute routing? Your controller also need to be derived from `ApiController`

Comment: @Nkosi yes, config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

Comment: public class Api must be inherit from Controller or ApiController

Comment: @Mate now it show "No route providing a controller name was found"

Comment: Great! you need to decorate with [Route("")] below  [HttpGet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to make sure you follow the suggested syntax for API controllers.

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class MyApiController: ApiController {
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")] // GET api
    public IHttpActionResult Get() {
        return Ok("API");
    }
}
```

Which includes having your controller derived from `ApiController`.

If using attribute routing with route prefix you still need to provide a route on the action.

`[Route("")]` in this case above will act as the default rout for that controller.